# Syntax error with python snake

Tags: python

Today I  completed a snake game tutorial for python/pygame and when I run it, this little error pops up.

```
File "raspberrysnake.py", line 52

    File "raspberrysnake.py"' line 52
    if changeDirection == 'right' and not
                                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code Section:

```
if changeDirection == 'right' and not
    direction == 'left':
direction == changeDirection
```

**What I want to know is, is 'not' a python syntax, and if not, is there some other syntax that does the same thing.**

P.S For anyone who wants to take a look at the code, here's a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/V5Fb14h3

Comment: First of all please learn about syntaxs of python and try to solve the error... Dont put your question directly here without doing proper homework

Comment: @RonakBhatt I've searched Google but to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

Use line continuation (`\`) if you want wrap lines ([Explicit line joining](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining)):

```
>>> changeDirection = ''
>>> if changeDirection == 'right' and not
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if changeDirection == 'right' and not
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> if changeDirection == 'right' and not \
... direction == 'left':
...     pass
...
```

Or surround the predicates with parentheses as  Trevor Senior commented ([Implicit line joining](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining)):

```
>>> if (changeDirection == 'right' and not
... direction == 'left'):
...     pass
...
```

BTW, body of the `if` block should be indented.

Comment: The parentheses help but then it comes up with another error.        `Traceback (most recent call last):` `    File "raspberrysnake.py", line 8, in <module>` `      playSurface = pygame.display.set.mode((640, 480))` `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set'

Comment: Also, I'm new to python.

Comment: @Auesome_Man3840, Please post another question.